# How to compute this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, modular-arithmetic

I want to sum the following:

$$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (i^3 \cdot (n \mod i))$$

Since the sum can be huge I have to output the sum modulo some given number m.
How can I approach this problem?

Also, n can be upto $10^{10}$.

Comment: What is the sum $k^3+(-k)^3$?

Comment: @almguest: I do not see how your comment could help. This is not $(\sum_{i=1}^n i^3)\pmod n$, there are no negative terms. The first values $f(n)$ are 
$0, 0, 8, 27, 126, 253, 693, 1204, 2418, 3801$.

Comment: I can't find it, but there was an almost identical problem here a day or two ago, about finding $\sum i^4[n/i]$ for very large $n$. Sounded like some sort of contest problem to me.

Comment: @Gerry I have deduced it from there only. I just wanted to know if this way is the correct way or not, and if it is how can i approach it. If its inappropriate, please don't answer.

Comment: Found it! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921772/find-the-value-of-summation [but it's closed, so not everyone can see it]

Comment: The contest for the underling [challenge](http://www.codechef.com/SEPT14/problems/FLOORI4) on Coderef has ended two days ago. [here](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/50953/floori4-editorial) is a link of the editorial of this particular problem.

Answer (score -1):

As Duplicate question of this has been deleted, I am posting the snapshot of answer posted there.[image]